# ESP32 Loop seems to hang

Tags: arduino-esp32, lora

I have the code below in my loop. I am receiving a message via a LoRa SX1278 module, which seems to work correctly. I had originally implemented a timer in a function to count down 30 seconds before turning off a relay. While this worked, it would stop the main loop from running and the device sending online updates of 30 seconds will run through the action.

I am trying to implement the code below so that when a message is received, I set a delay in milliseconds and execute when it matches. However, every time I uncomment the `NOAthu int`, the loop seems to hang when the if condition is met.

I can't for the life of me work out why. Identified section with "//<<<<<"

```c
void loop() {
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
  if (forceConfig) {
    Serial.println("Config Mode initiated");
    Serial.println("Turning the HotSpot On");
    launchWeb();
    startAP(); // Set up HotSpot
  }
  while ((WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(100);
  }
  float output_current =  abs((return_current_value(OUTPUT_CURRENT_SENSE_PIN))) ;
  AN_Pot1_Raw = analogRead(OUTPUT_CURRENT_SENSE_PIN);
  AN_Pot1_Filtered = readADC_Avg(output_current);
  delay(10);
  // SYNC States with on line
  if (digitalRead(LED) == 1) {
    digitalWrite(OUTPUT_PIN, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(OUTPUT_PIN, LOW);
  }
  // System Working-flash green light
  digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  if ((millis() - oldMillis) > flashgreenled2) {
    oldMillis = millis();
    digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  }
  // check for incoming msgs from LoRa
  if (output1 == "") {
    Online();
  }
  // check for incoming msgs
  if (output1 == tag1 || output1 == tag2) {
    output1 = "user";
    t0 = 0;
    Serial.println (" Turning on power user");
    Serial.println (" Turning on LED");
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH); // for testing
    RelayON();
    sendUpdate();
    output1 = ""; // clear the output string so no match found
  }
  // check for incoming msgs
  if (output1 == ctag1) {
    output1 = "user1";
    t0 = 0;
    Serial.println (" Turning on power for user1");
    Serial.println (" Turning on LED");
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH); // for testing
    RelayON();
    sendUpdate();
    output1 = ""; // clear the output string so no match found
  }
  // check for incoming msgs
  if (output1 == "NoAuth" && NOAuth == 0) {
    OffMillis = millis();
    NOAuth = 1; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< IF THIS ISN'T COMMENTED OUT, IT STOPS
    output1 = "";
    Serial.println("***************************************Initiated power off Timer");
    infoln(t0);
  }
  // Poweroff
  if ((millis() - OffMillis) == 1000) {
    Serial.println (" Turning off power");
    Serial.println (" Turning off LED");
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    RelayOFF();
    output1 = "";
    digitalWrite(OUTPUT_PIN, LOW);
    NOAuth == 0;
  }
  drd->loop();
}
```

I have tried bool with no change. I have it working if I create a timer "To++" within a function. However this is not ideal as it holds up the main loop and sending online status.

I should also mention that the relay it's controlling is a latched relay driven by a drv8210. so I only send an impulse to it to change state and it shouldn't just be energised on or off for long durations.

Answer (score 1):

Brain Fart,

I wasn't incrementing the current time. I changed my code to the below and results are stable. however im sure there is a simpler and cleaner way of implementing this.

```
// check for incoming msgs
  if (output1==ctag1)
  { output1="Cleaner";
    t0=0;
    Serial.println (" Turning on power for Cleaner");
    Serial.println (" Turning on LED");    
    digitalWrite(LED,HIGH); // for testing
    RelayON();
    sendUpdate();
    output1=""; // clear the output string so no match found
    NOAthu=0;
  
  }
   CurrentTime = millis();
  // check for incoming msgs
  if ((output1=="NoAuth") && (NOAthu==0)) {
  //currenttime = millis()
  NOAthu = 1;
  PrevMil = CurrentTime;
  output1="";
  Serial.println("Initated power off Timer");
    infoln(t0);
    
  }

 //Poweroff 
 if ((CurrentTime - PrevMil >= 10000) && (CurrentTime - PrevMil <= 18000)){
      NOAthu=0;  
      Serial.println (" Turning off power");
      Serial.println (" Turning off LED");
      digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
      RelayOFF();
      output1="";
      t0=0; 
      digitalWrite(OUTPUT_PIN,LOW);
```